# 2020 Moderators election — Interest poll / Élection des modératrices et modérateurs — sondage d'intérêt

Tags: discussion, moderation

**UPDATE 2020-04-29**

Comme nous avons reçus les intentions de se présenter de quatre personnes (en me comptant pour arriver à ce nombre plancher), les élections pourront bien se tenir. La première phase commence le 25 mai 2020, voir [la page dédiée](https://french.stackexchange.com/election/2) pour les détails du processus

---

Since we have received four statements of interest (counting myself to get to this minimal number of candidates), the election will actually happen. The first phase starts on May 25th 2020, see [the dedicated page](https://french.stackexchange.com/election/2) for more infos.

---

(English version below)

Nos modérateurs *pro tempore* ont été nommées en 2013 pendant la beta du site, ce qui commence à dater, d'autant que deux d'entre nous ayant démissionné, je me retrouve seul modérateur du site.
À présent que nous sommes sortis de la beta (l'an dernier déjà), nous pouvons organiser notre première vraie élection pour récupérer une équipe complète de trois modérateurices.

En lien avec l'équipe de CM de StackExchange, nous envisageons de tenir cette élection en avril ou en mai. Pour éviter de lancer le processus si aucun⋅e d'entre vous ne compte se présenter, nous aimerions sonder vos intentions :

**Si vous envisageriez de vous présenter à une élections des modératrices et modérateurs du site, merci de l'indiquer en répondant à ce post**

Il ne s'agit que d'un sondage d'intérêt et une simple réponse suffit, le fait d'avoir ou de ne pas avoir répondu à ce message ne changera rien à votre droit à participer à une éventuelle élection.

À titre informatif : *a priori* je ne compte pas me présenter à cette élection, sauf dans le cas où il y aurait moins de trois candidatures

---

Moderator Election — Community Interest Check

This community last had moderators appointed in 2013, so it's been a while... and the team's seen some recent departures too.

In addition to that, we have lost our "beta" label late last year! That means that in order to get a full team of 3 moderators again, we are entitled to have our first "full site" election. In talking with the CM team, we're looking at scheduling an election to start somewhere in April or May 2020. To avoid finding ourselves in a situation where an election would fail due to an insufficient number of candidates, though, I'm posting this to try to assess the community members' willingness to step up and nominate themselves, when the actual election's nomination period starts.

Please leave an answer if you'd be willing to run for a moderator position, should we decide to run an election. Like I mentioned, we're looking at scheduling the nomination period to start some time in April or May '20.

**NOTE:** This is not an official election nomination thread, just a "pulse check" to get a notion of how many people here would be willing to step up, so you don't have to put up your whole election nomination.

Comment: I would not be opposed, but I also think there are many others better suited. If it were otherwise going to fail for lack of candidates I would « me présenter ».

Comment: I would be interested, as I always kept an eye on French SE and started contributing again recently. However, I realize that I may not be fit for the job because of my lack of experience on this website, and I know a few people here who seem very active and helpful, so I would understand being refused if I applied.

Answer (score 1):

Je lève la main. Je serais possiblement intéressé a aider pour la modération.

Je suis modérateur déjà ailleurs sur le réseau donc je sais dans quoi je m'embarque. Je connais très bien les règlements du réseaux.

La seule choses par contre, même si je suis natif de la langue de Molière et née au Québec, je ne suis pas le meilleur dans ma grammaire.

L'avantage est que je suis dans le fuseau horaire PST-5, donc si d'autre modérateur(s) sont de l'Europe le site va être bien couvert dans le temps pour toutes urgence.